# Error in tsfresh feature extraction: TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, data-science-model

I'm trying to use the tsfresh library for feature extraction from time series data. Specifically, I'm using the extract_features function with the EfficientFCParameters as the default feature calculation parameters. However, I encountered an error and need help understanding and resolving it.

Here is my code:

```py
from tsfresh.feature_extraction import extract_features, EfficientFCParameters

extracted_features = extract_features(all_data, column_id='TimeSeriesID', column_sort='Date',
                                      default_fc_parameters=EfficientFCParameters())
```

And the error message I'm receiving is:

TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types
I'm not sure what could be causing this error or how to resolve it. Could someone please help me understand the issue and provide guidance on how to fix it?

Any assistance or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!